# SQL Server delete trigger returns select statement, how to capture that data?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

On a table, there's a delete trigger that performs some operations and then at the end, executes a select statement, so when you do something like...

```
delete from mytable where id=1
```

it returns a recordset.

Is there a way to save the results of that recordset into a temp table or something? I tried something like this:

```
declare @temptable table (returnvalue int);
insert into @temptable (returnvalue)
delete from mytable where id=1;
```

But apparently that syntax doesn't work.

Comment: You could save the results into a real table.   But you would have to do it inside the trigger code.  Not in the code that performs the delete.

Comment: As an aside (since this code might not be under your control), having a `DELETE` trigger return a result set is a terrible idea. Aside from being surprising, it makes it impossible to issue a `DELETE` as part of multi-statement code that has to return its own result set. If you want to have a result as part of a delete, use the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms177564).

Comment: WHY? Your true problem, and what your question should address, is why you are doing this.  A result set from a trigger is a very strange thing to be doing, fixing that design flaw should be your goal. What could possibly be your motivation to return a result set from a delete trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I can not imagine a situation that you need to return the recordset of the line you will delete using a trigger returning a recordset. But I am not here to judge your requests.

Well, you can use the OUTPUT to show the row data that will be excluded and enter this data into a temporary table. Follow the example below.

However you should know that: SQL Server does not guarantee the order in Which rows are processed and returned by DML statements using the OUTPUT clause. It is up to the application to include an WHERE clause Appropriate que can guarantee the Desired semantics, or Understand que When multiple rows may qualify for the DML operation, there is guaranteed in order. The Following example uses the subquery and you assume uniqueness is a characteristic of the column in order to DatabaseLogID in Place the Desired ordering semantics. See the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177564.aspx).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255)
);
GO

--DECLARE @MyTablePerson TABLE
--(
--    PersonID int,
--    LastName varchar(255),
--    FirstName varchar(255)
--);
--GO

--CREATE TRIGGER TRG_DLT_Person
--ON Person
--INSTEAD OF DELETE
--AS
--BEGIN

     -- Some code you want to do before delete

--     DELETE Person
--     FROM DELETED D
--END
--GO

insert into Person
(PersonID,
LastName,
FirstName)
values
(1,
'Kilmister',
'Lemmy');
GO

insert into Person
(PersonID,
LastName,
FirstName)
values
(2,
'Gilmour',
'David');
GO

insert into Person
(PersonID,
LastName,
FirstName)
values
(3,
'Rose',
'Axl');
GO

insert into Person
(PersonID,
LastName,
FirstName)
values
(4,
'Bullock',
'Sandra');
GO
```

--

```
select * from Person;
GO

delete from Person
--output deleted.* INTO @MyTablePerson
output deleted.*
WHERE PersonID = 4 OR PersonID = 2;
GO

select * from Person;
GO

select * from @MyTablePerson;
GO
```

I put the example I'm showing in a this environment, but in this environment believe that are not supported for temporary tables.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9007/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of this being a bad practice due to it being difficult for anyone interacting with the table to know that it will happen and deal with it when it does, and regardless of it being possible to capture, one pretty solid reason to *not* return result sets from a trigger is that doing so will be disallowed as of one of the next versions of SQL Server, so you would have to re-code the functionality anyway. The MSDN page for the [disallow results from triggers Server Configuration Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186337.aspx) states:

> **Important**
>
> This feature will be removed in the next version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. We recommend that you set this value to 1.

If you are merely returning something like `SELECT IdField FROM deleted;` from the trigger, then you should (well, really *need to*) use the [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause instead.

That being said, doing the following will do what you want:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TempResults
(
  ReturnValue INT
);

INSERT INTO #TempResults (ReturnValue)
  EXEC('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;');
```

You can test with the following:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.DeleteTriggerWithResults') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE dbo.DeleteTriggerWithResults;
END;

CREATE TABLE dbo.DeleteTriggerWithResults
(
  Col1 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Col2 DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_DeleteTriggerWithResults_d
ON dbo.DeleteTriggerWithResults
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT Col1
  FROM deleted;

END;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.DeleteTriggerWithResults DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 30

SELECT * FROM dbo.DeleteTriggerWithResults;
```

And then run the test:

```sql
DECLARE @TempResults TABLE (Col1 INT);

INSERT INTO @TempResults (Col1)
EXEC('
    DELETE TOP (10)
    FROM  dbo.DeleteTriggerWithResults;
');

SELECT * FROM @TempResults;
```

Returns:

> Col1
>   -------
>   10
>   9
>   8
>   7
>   6
>   5
>   4
>   3
>   2
>   1

Comment: Well, for completeness' sake, I feel obliged to mention that the "this feature will be removed" disclaimer tends to linger around SQL for years upon years before a feature is removed -- if ever. Point in case: this particular feature has been deprecated since 2008, but has still not been removed as of SQL Server 2014. `TEXT`, `NTEXT` and `IMAGE` have been deprecated for a decade, but are also still available. They should really replace "will" with "might" in that message...

Comment: @JeroenMostert True, but as of 2005 it was not noted as deprecated so their intention has been declared. I am aware that they sometimes let these things linger on, which is why I said within the next few versions instead of the next version. Also, if you look at the [Deprecated Database Engine Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) page, it was listed as **Not Supported in a Future Version** up through 2008 R2 and then **Not Supported in the Next Version** as of 2012. So they are getting closer to making this happen.